# Android Theme in APIDemos sample

Tags: java, android

I looked at the APIDemos examples for Android 4.2. All listView's items are seperated by a white line.

I created a simple project (Android 4.2), and changed style.xml to (instead of Theme.Light):

```
<style name="Theme" parent="android:Theme"> </style>
```

It displays the black background, but there is no white seperator line. I can not get the point how it set in APIDemos sample. could you help me?

I added `<item name="android:divider" >@android:color/white</item>`

but it does not work for the listView.

And this is my listView:

```
mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, mStrings);
```

Comment: I am using [Pull-To-Refresh Library](https://github.com/chrisbanes/Android-PullToRefresh) which make the dividers disappear in the ListView. 

I have no clue how to solve it, I appreciate if you help me in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Did you change the Theme in your Manifest?

Another possibility to customize a list is to define a ListView as an XML (my_list.xml). There you can add the attribut "android:divider". If you are working with fragments you can also call getListView in your onCreateView() after you inflating your my_list.xml.

Comment: That's not what I am looking for. I know how to set it from .xml. My question is about how it has been set in APIDemo sample.